# SVN - hudson connection error. Connection refused by server

Tags: svn, connection, hudson, svnkit

I'm using hudson build tool that points to SVN server. Recently SVN repository was migrated to another server with the same name. Now I'm able to view the repository in browser and I can do checkout, checkin in other tools like tortoise SVN. But the jobs in hudson that points to the same repository is failing. Below is the erroe message which I got.

```
Unable to access https://svm.acnielsen.com/repos/OnDemand/DimensionSourcing/tags/${APP_TAG}/datastage <https://svm.acnielsen.com/repos/OnDemand/DimensionSourcing/tags/%24%7bAPP_TAG%7d/datastage>  : svn: connection refused by the server
svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/repos/OnDemand/DimensionSourcing/tags/$%7BAPP_TAG%7D/datastage' (show details)

org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: connection refused by the server
svn: OPTIONS request failed on '/repos/OnDemand/DimensionSourcing/tags/$%7BAPP_TAG%7D/datastage'


 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:106)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:90)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:629)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:275)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:263)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:516)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:98)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1001)
 at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.testConnection(DAVRepository.java:97)
 at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.checkRepositoryPath(SubversionSCM.java:1842)
 at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.doCheckRemote(SubversionSCM.java:1783)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor206.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
```

If enter password, it shows like connection refused by server. If I'm able to connect server via other clients, then what is the issue with hudson.

Can anyone please help on this issue? I'm searching for the solution for two days.